# Why must I add a DataGridView to a Form in order to get the data?

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview, datasource, rowcount

I had to copy a datagridview to another, in order to iterate through it within a backgroundworker thread, creating an excel export.

The copy was made to allow users to made some changes in the original datagridview, during the export.

So I created a new DataGridView (programatically), and put a copy of the original DataTable into the DataSource property of the new DataGridView.
However, I figured out that if I don't add the datagridview in the Controls (list) property of any Form, the RowCount still equals to 0...

Can someone can explain this?

Note : The copy of the DataTable is just a new DataTable with copy() of Columns.

Comment: Can you show your code of defining the new `DataGridView`, set the `DataSource` and where you check the `RowCount`.

Comment: I don't have the code here, but it's something like that :

Comment: The DataGridView might be waiting for some Window Messages before it reads the DataTable, I am not sure about this. For a reason like this, there are two timers in .Net one for Window Forms and one for standalone usage... Is there anything you need to do in the DataGridView that you cannot do with the DataTable (or a View of it)?

Comment: Why are you using a UI component here? Why do you want the data in `DataGridView` **at all** ?

Comment: I don't have the code here, but it's something like that :

public DataGridView void Copy(DataTable dt)
{
   DataGridView newGV = new DataGridView();
   newGV.DataSource = dt.Copy();
   return newGV;
}

When I spy the returned object, I always get a RowCount value equals to 0.

I juste have to put : 
Form ghostForm = new Form();
ghostForm.Controls.Add(newGV);

Before the DataSource setting to have the rows.
Note that the problem here is not the "rowcount" but the data that are not loaded unless I put the previous code...

Comment: @Stephan : According to me, it's something like that...
Actually, as the user can change the column positions and the visible properties of them, I need these properties to create my Excel file to reproduce the same behaviour.

It's why I need a UI component here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite simple. When you just created your DataGridView (or any other WinForms or Wpf control) it is created only in .Net. E.g. there is no system window created for it. And while control is in this state, it don't apply any bindings for optimization purposes (why should visual control do anything, while it is invisible? :)). When you add your control to the **visible** form, control will have its system window created (i.e. its Handle property will be initialized) and it will start work as expected.
If you want to make any visual control to work as intented, but not really show it, you simply need to read its Handle property. This will force control to create a system window and fully initialize.
Also for WPF it is a bit harder, because you can get a handle only for Window control and in order to get it you have to use following code:

```
public IntPtr GetWpfWindowHandle(Window w)
{
   var interopHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(w);
   return interopHelper.Handle;
}
```

Comment: Thank you :)
I saw that a BindingContext property was set when I attached the DGC to a form, so I expected something like that.
Again, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340787/databinding-a-datagridview-control-which-is-not-in-form-controls-collection) for an answer. In that instance, just reading the Handle didn't work - I needed to assign a BindingContext to the grid.