# Databinding a DataGridView control which is not in Form.Controls collection?

Tags: data-binding, datagridview

I have a custom control which inherits from DataGridView. It augments the control with some additional functionality *(which exports the contents of each cell)*. I would like to use this functionality, but don't need the UI of the grid itself.

So, I create an instance of the custom control, set the DataSource property to an instance of a DataTable, and... no columns in the grid. My DataTable has columns *(and rows)*, AutoGenerateColumns is true, but no columns appear in the grid "Columns" collection. The fact that its a custom control becomes irrelevant at this point, because the DataGridView control does the same.

If I add the grid to a form's "Controls" collection, the data binding works, and the grid has my columns.

Why is that ?

```
  public Form1()
  {
     InitializeComponent();

     DataTable dataTable = new DataTable() { TableName = "Bob" };
     dataTable.Columns.Add("One",typeof(String));
     dataTable.Columns.Add("Two", typeof(String));
     dataTable.Columns.Add("Three", typeof(String));
     dataTable.Rows.Add("a", "b", "c");
     dataTable.Rows.Add("d", "e", "f");
     dataTable.Rows.Add("g", "h", "i");

     DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();

     grid.DataSource = dataTable;
     int n1 = grid.Columns.Count; // returns zero

     this.Controls.Add(grid); // why do I have to do this ?

     grid.DataSource = null;
     grid.DataSource = dataTable;
     int n2 = grid.Columns.Count; // returns three
  }
```

Thanks,
Ross

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why must I add a DataGridView to a Form in order to get the data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256762/why-must-i-add-a-datagridview-to-a-form-in-order-to-get-the-data)

Comment: Yes... it seems a duplicate of that question. However, just reading the "Handle" property of the grid *(as suggested in answer to that post)* doesn't seem to affect the bound columns *(in this instance)*.

Comment: Yes - I tried that myself and couldn't make it work. Personally I'd take a step back and reconsider using a UI component for non ui work. Is it possible to extract your logic to work on a datasource rather than the cells collection?

Comment: In an ideal world I would, but in a world of 20yr old monolithic code bases, a 5-line hack *(using existing tried and tested components)* is better than a couple of hundred lines of new untested code. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David Hall's comment led me to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256762/why-must-i-add-a-datagridview-to-a-form-in-order-to-get-the-data), which led me to look into the BindingContext of the grid. Sure enough, it's null, but by creating a new BindingContext for the grid control, binding the grid to the DataTable now populates the "Columns" collection.

```
  public Form1()
  {
     InitializeComponent();

     DataTable dataTable = new DataTable() { TableName = "Bob" };
         :

     DataGridView grid = new DataGridView { Name = "Tom" };

     grid.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
     grid.DataSource = dataTable;

     int n1 = grid.Columns.Count; // returns three
  }
```

Curiously enough, the order in which you set the binding context or the data source appears not to matter !