# DataGridView doesn't accept DataSource when invoked via Unit test

Tags: c#, data-binding, .net-4.0, datagridview, datasource

The code works fine when invoked via UI but doesn't work when called via unit test. I was able to repro this for simple Winform App.

```
namespace WinFormApp
{
    public class Pair
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class FormManager
    {
        List<Pair> _source = new List<Pair>()
        {
            new Pair() { Key="1", Value = "one" },
            new Pair() { Key = "2", Value = "two" }
        };

        public FormManager(DataGridView dgv)
        {
            dgv.DataSource = _source;
        }
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            FormManager manager = new FormManager(dataGridView1); // This works
        }
    }
}
```

Unit test code

```
namespace WinFormApp.Test
{
    [TestClass()]
    public class FormManagerTest
    {
        private DataGridView dataGridView1;

        [TestMethod()]
        public void FormManagerTestSource()
        {
            this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();

            FormManager target = new FormManager(dataGridView1);

            Assert.AreEqual(2, dataGridView1.Rows.Count); // This fails.
        }
    }
}
```

Following code was generated by designer

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // dataGridView1
    // 
    this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
    this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 27);
    this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
    this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(240, 150);
    this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
    // 
    // Form1
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
    this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
    this.Name = "Form1";
    this.Text = "Form1";
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
    this.ResumeLayout(false);

}
```

My guess is I'm missing some kind of init call on dataGridView1 object in unit test code path. But using designer generated code in unit test didn't help. Has this to do with actual object associated with a `Form` object?

Comment: @AustinSalonen dataGridView1.Rows.Count is 0. It should be 2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding `dataGridView1.BindingContext = new BindingContext();` makes this work. This answer helped.
[Databinding a DataGridView control which is not in Form.Controls collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340787/databinding-a-datagridview-control-which-is-not-in-form-controls-collection)

```
[TestMethod()]
public void FormManagerTestSource()
{
    this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
    FormManager target = new FormManager(dataGridView1);
    Assert.AreEqual(0, dataGridView1.Rows.Count); // 0 initially.
    dataGridView1.BindingContext = new BindingContext(); // this makes it work.
    Assert.AreEqual(2, dataGridView1.Rows.Count); // 2 as expected.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are trying to implement integration testing rather than unit testing

I don't see where you are setting the datasource for the dataGridView1

in your WinFormApp you are setting the datasource like:

```
 List<Pair> _source = new List<Pair>()
    {
        new Pair() { Key="1", Value = "one" },
        new Pair() { Key = "2", Value = "two" }
    };

    public FormManager(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        dgv.DataSource = _source;
    }
```

Unit tests should be void of environment requirements you should mock as much as possible so that your test is focused on one point.
Look at :https://nuget.org/packages/Moq/4.0.10827

Create a separate test for each component or unit

I see you are trying to verify the row count

try:

```
 [TestClass()]
public class FormManagerTest
{


    [TestMethod()]
    public void FormManagerTestSource()
    {
        var dgv = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        var _source = new List<Pair>()
    {
        new Pair() { Key="1", Value = "one" },
        new Pair() { Key = "2", Value = "two" }
    };
        Assert.AreEqual(2, _source.Count); 
        //If you want to test dgv row count
        dgv.DataSource = _source;
        Assert.AreEqual(2, dataGridView1.Rows.Count);

    }
}
```

Comment: This question isn't about unit test vs integration testing. It's about DataGridView not working when instantiated beyond windows form envt. In above code, does your test `FormManagerTestSource` pass? It is failing for me.